# Do I need a CDN for a single country website?

Tags: image, video, optimization, cdn

I'm planning to build a website. I want it to be as optimized as possible, so I was thinking of also using a CDN for images and video's etc.

The website will only be for one country (the Netherlands, a very small country). 
Do I really benefit from using a CDN in this case?

If a CDN is not needed, would it still be recommended to put that type of content in for example a sub domain (content.mydomain.com or cdn.mydomain.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a CDN such that people who live in another country have less loading time for images and videos and such. In your case, if only people in the Netherlands are connecting to your website, there is hardly any benefit between serving images and videos from Groningen (in the north of the Netherlands) or Maastricht (in the south of the Netherlands). And it's also not needed to put it in a subdomain. Just keep it well-organized, like put the images of the website in a www.domain.com/images folder.

Answer (score 0):

You will benefit from CDN if that is not costing much, users of your website want a fast loading site, and also if there are many users. 
Keep in mind that the browser that will display the page to end-user will be on his machine, and one of the aim of web development is to provide a better user experience.

When your browser downloads a html page, it tries to download associated resources like stylesheets, javascript, images, video etc. also to complete the download of page and rendering it in browser. Every browser has a concurrent request limit per hostname. So, till that limit, browser can download things in parallel from a hostname. Then there is Max connections limit in the browser. Other items are queued and start downloading as first items finish downloading. Check network tab in chrome for www.microsoft.com or any other heavy site like facebook and you can see it happening.

By using CDN, you are providing more hostnames to browser to download stuff, so parallel downloads increase. Page load is faster for end user.

Also, do note that your images should be web optimized for size and scale. They should not be bigger in size and then scaled to smaller content area. Take care that if not required, your video should not autoplay as page is being rendered.

Also, it will be much better if you can use content expiry for images hosted over cdn, or css or js files. Content which have been downloaded by browser, has a far-future content expiry date ( more than few months ), and is currently available in the cache does not cost a network request to download the content. Here, i am assuming that you are already doing content bundling and minification for js and css.

If you need to check more over the web, you can check for Steve Souders or Web performance optimization.